# Append queries in URL instead of removing them using Express.js?

Tags: javascript, html, express, filter, get

I have a form like this:  " method="GET">
and I'm trying that the selected values of that form, complement the "urlInfo" queries, but instead they are substituting them. For example:
urlInFo= localhost:8080/product?id=123
and when selecting a value in the forms, instead of doing this:
urlInFo= localhost:8080/product?id=123&valueSelected=888
it substitutes the already existing query parameter giving this:
urlInFo= localhost:8080/product?valueSelected=888
I've been looking for a solution that makes this possible or a way to keep the original queries in my url in order to add them more.

I´m trying to do this because I create some filters in a shop page, so the purpose is to add that new queries params obtained in the forms, to the already existing ones obtained from a selected type of product.

Comment: correction: I have a form like this:  form action="<%=urlInfo%>" method="GET"